# Filter an associative array to only retain elements with whitelisted keys

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, associative-array, whitelist

I am having array like below.

```
$a = [
    [id] => 18162876
    [name] => phpuG4fhx
    [type] => Video
    [created] => 2016-02-11T16:55:54+00:00
    [updated] => 2016-02-11T16:55:54+00:00
    [duration] => 14.975
    [hashed_id] => uzyng792la
    [description] => 
    [progress] => 0
    [status] => queued
    [thumbnail] => Array
        (
            [url] => https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/c2b1eb4bdf6f872fb9da416994973a5358b31868.jpg?image_crop_resized=200x120&video_still_time=7
            [width] => 200
            [height] => 120
        )

    [account_id] => 410090];
```

In that, I need to fillter only `[hashed_id]` and `[thumbnail]`.

Comment: `echo $a['hashed_id'];` is this?

Comment: `$a = array_filter($a[0], function($key) { return $key === 'hashed_id' || $key === 'thumbnail'; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);` (PHP >= 5.6.0)

Comment: Filter in only one record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking but...

If you want to access the elements of the array you can use the following format:

`$array[$key]`

For your example it would be: `$a['hashed_id']`

If you want to filter the array so it only contains the `hashed_id` and the `thumbnail` then you could do something like:

```
$filteredArray = [];
$filteredArray['hashed_id'] = $a['hashed_id'];
$filteredArray['thumbnail'] = $a['thumbnail'];
```

And then you have an array only containing the `hashed_id` and the `thumbnail`.

If that answers your question, great; if not you may want to clarify what it is your after after you 'filter' your array. What is your expected outcome, etc?

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4];

var_dump(array_filter($arr, function($k) {
    return ($k == 'a') || ($k == 'b');
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

Or use:

If you're using PHP >= 5.6 you can now set a flag to filter on array key instead of array value:

```
$allowed = ['foo', 'bar'];
$filtered = array_filter(
    $my_array,
    function ($key) use ($allowed) {
        return in_array($key, $allowed);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```